# Command prompt: finding files

Tags: file, find, command, command-prompt, prompt

I just started working with command prompt and I can't figure out how to do some things. I need to:

- find the largest and oldest file
- display directory from older to newer files
- count files

I've read a book, searched the web and command prompt's help section, and still nothing! If you could help me, it would really mean a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DIR` command is he start.

From the prompt, `dir /?` will display the options available.

```
DIR/o:s
dir/o:d
dir/o:-d
```

may be useful.

The filecount is also displayed in a `dir` listing.

Comment: thank you so so much, it works! :D awesome. i thought i'd never solve this problem. thanks!